# How to automate window page login using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In my web based application login form is window popup ,so that its not possible to automate using selenium webdriver , i have tried using robot class but didn't get the result, can any one suggest a solution for it.

[image: my login form is like below]

Answer (score 0):

if its authentication then you can try sending username password in URL. Also take a look at AutoIT for such cases.
EDIT: It depends on the type of authentication like HTTP / HTTPS so on and so-forth
One example can be this: https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters/371918

Comment: check Edit..also you can look at AutoIT option as that would be true testing as user would do..there's already lot of content over internet for what you want to achieve using AutoIt